With Jenkins using the 'gerrit-trigger' plugin is it possible to start a job that gets send to Gerrit programmatically?
After having created a Gerrit patch-set the normal way, a Jenkins job gets spawned with certain parameters tying it to the change set:
GERRIT_BRANCH = 'main'
GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION = '0f036b8a0fcc3211a93184e2e9613f2358ad2a23'
GERRIT_EVENT_TYPE = 'patchset-created'
GERRIT_REFSPEC = 'refs/changes/91/85991/1'
GERRIT_HASHTAGS = ''
GERRIT_CHANGE_SUBJECT = 'some change'
GERRIT_CHANGE_ID = 'I5b2c81dc25557f95b9caf00cfce70a3f4fd4d16a'
GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_NAME = 'Mickey Mouse'

This is because I have Jenkins running the gerrit-trigger plugin.
In Jenkins web UI I can now Rebuild that build and even add/change job specific parameters, and the newly spawned build will also be sent to Gerrit and gets attached as a validating build to that change set!
Now I'm trying to do that in a scriptable way by running
build(
    job: "path/to/my/job",
    parameters: [
        stringParam(name: "GERRIT_REFSPEC", value: "refs/changes/91/85991/1"),
        stringParam(name: "GERRIT_CHANGE_ID", value: "I5b2c81dc25557f95b9caf00cfce70a3f4fd4d16a"),
        stringParam(name: "GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION", value: "0f036b8a0fcc3211a93184e2e9613f2358ad2a23"),
        stringParam(name: "GERRIT_BRANCH", value: "main"),
        stringParam(name: "GERRIT_EVENT_TYPE", value: "patchset-created"),
        stringParam(name: "GERRIT_HASHTAGS", value: ""),
        stringParam(name: "GERRIT_CHANGE_SUBJECT", value: "some change"),
        stringParam(name: "GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_NAME", value: "Mickey Mouse"),
    ],
)

.. from within a Groovy script.
But while the build is being created successfully and it shows no difference to the one I started via Rebuild, this time it's not being sent to Gerrit and added to the change set.
Is there some trick I have to apply in order to let a programmatically/manually spawned build behave like the one I trigger via Rebuild in terms of Gerrit?
Is there any way I can debug what's going on here?

You can start by looking at the Jenkins system log, errors would go there. Or make a custom logger for com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.
